# Call to a member function subMinutes() on string

Tags: laravel, carbon

estoy realizando un proceso, donde extraigo de una view el campo `hora` y es tipo `date`, por ejemplo trae de vuelta 11:00, a esto yo necesito restarle 10 minutos (estoy trabajando con laravel) y estoy realizando lo siguiente

```
$fecha = Carbon::now();
 $viewPersonas::ViewPersonas::whereRaw("to_char(fecha, 'YYYY-MM-DD')='".$fecha->format('Y-m-d')."'")->get();
 foreach ($viewPersonas as $per){
    $hr = $per->hor  //Esto me imprime 11:00
    $hrs =  $hr->subMinutes(10);  //Estaba usando Carbon
 }
```

Pero cada vez que imprimo `$hrs`, la consola me trae de vuelta este error **Call to a member function subMinutes() on string**, cómo poder solucionarlo y que mi variable `$hr->subMinutes(10)`, me arroje los 10 minutos restantes, o quizás no es con el mpetodo de Carbon como debo hacerlo, que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas que carbon lo *entienda* como tiempo y no como una cadena de texto que de hecho es lo que pasa en este momento, entonces alcanza con hacer esto:

```
$fechaFormateada = now()->parse($per->hor);
```

Y posterior ya puedes aplicar el método que reste los minutos, pero sobre la variable que almacena el parseo de la *hora*

```
$fechaFormateada->subMinutes(10);
```

Finalmente para evitar que salga la marca de año, mes y día también puedes emplear el método `toTimeString()` del siguiente modo:

```
$fechaFormateada->subMinutes(10)->toTimeString();
```

**Fuentes de consulta**

- [String Formating](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting)

Comment: Muchas gracias @BetaM, me ayudaste a entender lo que necesitaba hacer y a poner en práctica esto. Gracias